# Filtering array by multiple conditions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, filtering

I have an array of objects corresponding to HTML elements. These are cards which should appear/disappear depending on whether the condition is satisfied. I've converted the HTMLCollection to a Javascript array so I can use array methods on it.

I'm also using HTML select tags to generate a javascript object to use as a filter. I need to know how to filter my array by all of the key/value pairs on the object. Right now my code is only satisfying one condition, the most recent condition.

Here is the HTML:

```
<label for="numProperties"></label>
<label for="location"></label>
<label for="retired"></label>

<select class="filter" id="numProperties" onchange="updateFilters(this.value)">
    <option value="none" selected disabled hidden>Choose Num Properties</option>
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select class="filter" id="location" onchange="updateFilters(this.value)">
    <option value="none" selected disabled hidden>Choose Location</option>
    <option value="all">All Locations</option>
    <option value="New York">New York</option>
    <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
</select>

<select class="filter" id="retired" onchange="updateFilters(this.value)">
    <option value="none" selected disabled hidden>Choose If Retired</option>
    <option value="true">Yes</option>
    <option value="false">No</option>
</select>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
        function updateFilters(value) {
        var filters = document.getElementsByClassName('filter');
        var activeFilters = {};

        for (var i = filters.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (filters[i].value != 'none' && filters[i].value != 'all') {
                activeFilters[filters[i].id] = filters[i].value;
            }
        }

            filterCards(activeFilters)
        }

        function filterCards(activeFilters) {
        var test = allCards.filter(function (card) {
            for (var key in activeFilters) {
                if (card.attributes[key].value === activeFilters[key]) {
                   card.style.display = 'inline-block' 
                } else {
                   card.style.display = 'none'
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

As you can see, I need to be able to filter for any/all of the conditions. People with 2 properties living in New York who are retired. Right now my filter only works for the most recent search. If I select a new location, for example, my array will show me everything in that new location, even if the objects in that array have a different number of properties or a different boolean value for "retired".

Comment: So if card matches all the filters, you set display to 'none', otherwise 'inline-block'?

Comment: sorry, my mistake, should be the other way around. i've edited now.

Answer (score 0):

You need a 'break' inside your for loop when a filter doesn't match:

```js
for (var key in activeFilters) {
  if (card.attributes[key].value === activeFilters[key]) {
    card.style.display = 'inline-block' 
  } else {
    card.style.display = 'none'
    break; // stop filtering this card
    }
}
```